# The function that will be run after beforeFilter in CakePHP

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp

I work on a project that is before written by CakePHP.

I should modify and change the codes.

I couldn't find when it goes to **login** page.

I type an address before login into the application and it drives me to **login** page.

I trace the function and I understand that after finishing **before filter** the authentication run, but I don't know, which function does it.

[image]

As you see on the photo the _unauthenticated function use redirect to go to the login page but why all of them are the codes from CakePHP lib and there is no code which is written in application?

I appreciate you in advanced.

Comment: cake php use `Auth` component. so it should be in your login code.BTW i am not fully getting your question

Comment: @Alive to Die I add a photo to the question more explications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirect is coming from CakePHP's AuthComponent. This component uses the `Controller.startup` event which is the same event that triggers your controller's `beforeFilter` method to check for unauthenticated users and redirect them.

The [AuthComponent::startup](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php#L266-L269) is the 3rd function in the stack trace you pasted. After component startup hooks are complete, then the controller action is invoked, but only if the event was not stopped, which AuthComponent does when a user is not authenticated.

Comment: After logged into the application I want to go to applications links but because of the cookie (I enter a cookie that is not correct), it goes to the login page.  which part of auth code check the login?!
thanks

Comment: in the function :    protected function _getUser() {$user = $this->user();....}
$this->user() is null